# Invalid SDK version when running expo project

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo

I'm using expo for building react native mobile apps.everything was fine with skd 31 . recently when i tried to init a new app, it keeps telling:Error, Invalid sdkVersion.(It seems sdkVersion 31 and lower versions are supported)
when I change the sdk version in package.json to 31 it works well.but with the sdk version 33 it's showing the error.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling expo, Deleting appdata and chache and again installing expo-cli, Deleting node_module folder of my project and running expo-cli installation command But nothing changes.Still the same error.
I've read a solution that is installing xde but it's no longer supported by expo.and I could not find the software.
I want to.
I've tried the exact installation steps in my pc(I had not install expo on my pc and sdkversion 33 is it's first one) and it's working fine with version 33.But my laptop that was working with version 31 before and now it throws the error.

(UPDATE)
I just uninstalled and reinstalled my windows and It's now working well without issue.maybe some files of old expo were not deleted and it wouldn't support higher than sdk Version 31.Anybody knows were the expo files are installed? (except npm folder and npm-cache in appdata folder)

Comment: Show me the error-causing code. Helps you solve problems.

Comment: what do you mean by error causing?I'm trying to run a blank initialized app

Comment: Are you saying that you changed the sdk version to 33 and executed it?

Comment: I just ran init new project and error just begun

Comment: Were you tried this? `npm install -g expo-cli` => `expo init newproject` => `cd newproject` => `expo start`

Comment: in drive C, as i'm doing in my pc and is working well

Answer (score 0):

to fix the issue:

```
1. npm uninstall -g expo-cli --save
2. npm install -g expo-cli --save 
3. cd ~/.expo/cache
4. rm -rf everything that is in there
5. go back to your project
6. run expo start
```